# How to activate t1lib?

Tags: centos

Using CentOS el6.x86_64. I installed `t1lib` this way:

1. Installing RPMForge Repository

   ```
   wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
   rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
   ```
2. Importing RPMForge Repository Key

   ```
   wget http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
   rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
   ```
3. Finally install `t1lib`

   ```
   yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install t1lib
   ```

Package installed - no problem

Q. Do I need to do anything else to "activate" `t1lib`?

When I check `phpinfo`, isn't it suppose to show under "GD" heading? I'm not seeing it there.

Answer (score 1):

There's this comment on the PHP website concerning the `t1lib` library.

> Note: This function is only available if PHP is compiled using --with-t1lib[=DIR] .

*Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepstext.php*

I found that link when I was looking at the `t1lib` project's website.

> t1lib is useful for adding text to images using the gd library. When t1lib and gd are combined with an [Apache web server](http://www.apache.org/) that is [powered by the web scripting language php](http://www.php.net/), web developers can easily add captions, graph legends, logos, copyright notices, etc to images. See the php documentation for an example snippet of php code using t1lib to lay some text on an image: [php function imagepstext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepstext.php) (the example code is in the user notes dated 22-May-2001 at the very bottom of the page)

*Source: http://www.t1lib.org/*

#### Checking a build for t1lib support

If it were present running this command would show it:

```
$ php -i |& grep t1lib
```

My build doesn't include it either.

#### Rebuilding PHP

If you want this you'll have to rebuild PHP. You can follow these directions roughly on how one can rebuild the PHP RPM.

- http://cheesefather.com/2010/08/centos-install-php-5-2-with-t1lib-support/